# unable to be compiled

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


template < class T >
void swap (T& a, T& b)
{
    T temp = a; 
    a = b;
    b = temp;
}

int main ()
{
    char a = 'a';
    char b = 'b';
    swap (a, b);
    cout << "a = " << a << endl;
    cout << "b = " << b << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

the code can not be compiled under linux KDE command line (gcc compiler).
however if I change "using namespace std" into "using std::cout; using std::cin using std::endl" the program can be compiled and run well. what's wrong with it?
Thank you very much

Comment: What is the *exact* error message that you get?

Comment: Perhaps if you mentioned why it "can not be compiled"? Like ... the error message? We're not clairvoyant.

Comment: Just use **std::cout** instead of **cout** and likewise when you use **using namespace std**

Comment: What kind of problem are you seeing?  My guess is the compiler is getting confused because of std::swap.  There is probably a template specialization defined in the header you have included.

Comment: @DumbCoder: Did you read the entire Q? Your suggestion indicates you didn't.

Comment: @DumbCoder - erm, see, the point of the `using` statement is so you don't have to do that.

Comment: Why all the downvotes, jeez? The question isn't THAT bad.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is 'using namespace std;' considered a bad practice in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-a-bad-practice-in-c)

Comment: @jrok: I've downvoted because the OP *still* hasn't posted the error message, which would (very likely) identify the problem immediately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what VC++ says:

```
error C2668: 'swap' : ambiguous call to overloaded function
1>          c:\lisp\other\test_meth\test_meth.cpp(7): could be 'void swap<char>(T &,T &)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T=char
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\utility(100): or       'void std::swap<char>(_Ty &,_Ty &)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=char
1>          ]
1>          while trying to match the argument list '(char, char)'
```

The problem is: std namespace already contains the template function swap.

Answer (score 8):

Your definition of `swap` is conflicting with the already existing definition of `std::swap` when you bring `std` in the global namespace using `using namespace`.

Note that the conflict occurs when you try to instantiate the template, you can use

```
::swap (a, b);
```

to choose explicitly your definition.